# How to get total number of words in a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I was trying to count the total number of words in a sentence. I have used the following code in Javascript.

```
function countWords(){
    s = document.getElementById("inputString").value;
    s = s.replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/gi,"");
    s = s.replace(/[ ]{2,}/gi," ");
    s = s.replace(/\n /,"\n");
    alert(s.split(' ').length);
}
```

So if I gave following inputs,

```
"Hello world"  -> alerts 2       //fine
"Hello world<space>" -> alerts 3 // supposed to alert 2
"Hello world world" -> alerts 3  //fine
```

Where I went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one please:

```
var word = "str";
function countWords(word) {
    var s = word.length;
    if (s == "") {
        alert('count is 0')
    }
    else {
        s = s.replace (/\r\n?|\n/g, ' ')
            .replace (/ {2,}/g, ' ')
            .replace (/^ /, '')
            .replace (/ $/, '');
        var q = s.split (' ');
        alert ('total count is: ' + q.length);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you always format your code so terribly? Fixed it for you.

Comment: Why are you comparing the `.length` to `""`?

Comment: not comparing but if it is 0 words it's alert time

Answer (score 2):

here you will find all you need.

http://jsfiddle.net/deepumohanp/jZeKu/

```
var regex = /\s+/gi;
var wordCount = value.trim().replace(regex, ' ').split(' ').length;
var totalChars = value.length;
var charCount = value.trim().length;
var charCountNoSpace = value.replace(regex, '').length;

$('#wordCount').html(wordCount);
$('#totalChars').html(totalChars);
$('#charCount').html(charCount);
$('#charCountNoSpace').html(charCountNoSpace);
```

Answer (score 0):

Split will split event if there is your separator (in your case `' '`) at the end of the string, resulting in creating a last `[]` item in the list.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use the `split(" ")` function (including the space inside quotation) to convert the string to an array consisting of only the words. Then you can get the length of the array by using `array.length` which would essentially be the number of words in your string.